# Iterate over multiple MySQL tables, export 1 table from each

Tags: sql, mysql

I have around 150 MySQL databases, I need to export 1 table from each of the databases.

Is this possible, username and password are identical for each DB.

Comment: Really usernames and password are identical! Wow....

Comment: Are all tables named the same?

Comment: I shouldn't really comment as I don;t know your set up, but having identical u/p could become a security breach.. But like I said I don;t know your setup.

Comment: Its a local database, data isnt at all sensitive just a bunch of subject names, maths, english, sciecne etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more compact way to do it but this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -B -e "show databases" | egrep -v "Database|information_schema" | while read db; 
do 
  echo "$db"; 
  mysqldump $db TableName > $db.sql
done
```

You may need to tweak the `mysql` and `mysqldump` calls depending on your connection information.

Comment: mysqldump --no-create-info $db TableName >> mydump.sql

I guess this will create a single dump file.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, iteration would be more appropriate (rather than recursion).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, I'd suggest writing a simple bash script that cycles the 150 DB URLs and calls mysqldump on each one.

Answer (score 0):

See [link text](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3945/get-metadata-on-mysql-databases/), it generates meta data for all databases and all tables, you may be able to adapt it to export data for you. However this is in PHP and I am not certain of the language you wish to use..